# amfPHP Function Input Trouble

Tags: php, flash, amf, amfphp

I'm writing an amfPHP function which should take string input. It takes alphanumeric characters without a problem, but unfortunately it returns data as "2" if I send "2.UgnFl4kAWovazp_tVo6fHg__.86400.1260025200-571701419" as parameter.

here is the function (real simple as you can see)

```
function checkOpenSession($guid, $session_key) {
        return $session_key;
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty simple. You'll probably want to show the code calling the method, and the code that prints out the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this with a simple setup, and just writing the results to a file from the service browser and it seems to be ok for me. So the problem would seem to be in the calling end.

Another possibility is that amfphp changes the datatype of the returned value from a string to an int because of the leading integer. Try putting a some alphanumeric character at the start of the return string and see what that does.

Comment: You are right about amfphp, it changes string to an integer, when I put alpha char at the beginning of string, it returns right value with my added string. Do you know solution or setting to avoid this? (If I cannot find any solution, I'll put a char as temporary solution)

Comment: I did a quick test echoing strings that have that format and php doesn't seem to convert them. So then you'd need to find a setting from amfphp that turns that off. I don't think there is one though. It's also possible that it's the AS front end that does the conversion. Are you using AS2 or AS3? AS3 should be type safe.

Answer (score 3):

To bypass this service browser bug, double quote your entry on the service browser if you expect a string on an argument and this string starts with a number. I was having the same problem testing some methods via service browser and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is actually present in the AMFPHP service browser(bug), so it is easy to mistake it as the AMFPHP that is converting number-leading strings to int. However the problem is in the sending code. For instance sending a urlencoded string through the json gateway works properly (Objective C code):

```
NSString *theUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/modules/amfphp/amfphp/json.php/MysqlRemoting.checkAuth/%@/%@/1", kServerBaseUrl, userName, passMD5];
NSString *encodedUrl = [theUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Where passMD5 may have a leading number. But if I enter appropriate values for the checkAuth method in the service browser, it is broken.

[edit]

```
$value = urldecode($value);
if($value != "") {
if($value[0] != '[' && $value[0] != '{' && $value != "null" && $value != "false" && $value != "true") {
$hasAlpha = false;
//check to see if it is a number
$sl = strlen($value);
for ($i = 0; $i < $sl; $i++) {
    $char1 = ord($value[$i]);
    if($char1 >= 0x30 && $char1 <= 0x39) {
    //Then this is a number
    } else { //Else leave value as is */
    $hasAlpha = true;
    }
    }
    if (!$hasAlpha) $value = json_decode($value, true);
}
        else
        {
            $value = json_decode($value, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2 years later I moved the site that proves the above (that it's in the sending code) to a new machine, and it turns out that the problem is in amfphp (or perhaps in php 5.3 implementation of json_decode vs that of 5.2. anyway, in amfphp/core/json/app/actions.php, line 48 it decodes the param and checks only the first char to see if it should json_decode it (i.e to strip the quotes from a number). If its a number followed by any letters  you get null (on php 5.3 at least; again, it worked before for me on 5.2. Below I'm commenting in my change to the code to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

double quote your strings... that will work it out.